# CSS inline-block causing extra space between 2 vertical divs

Tags: css

I have several div (`class="badge"`) to display in the vertical. Not sure why I got extra space between 2 div in FF and IE (Chrome works fine).

I need them to display either no space or equal space in all browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/2hxak/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="stat-badges">
    <div class="badge">
        <div class="stat-num">123456</div>
    </div>
    <div class="badge">
        <div class="stat-num">0</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.stat-badges {
  text-align: center;
  width: 55px;
}
.badge {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  color: #ffffff;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #999999;
}
.badge .stat-num {
  max-width: 30px;
  min-width: 20px;
  padding: 3px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

The space will disappear if I remove `overflow: hidden;`. I keep `overflow: hidden` with `ellipse` to crop long text.

Comment: is there reason to use here display: inline-block instead of display: block?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change `vertical-align: baseline;` to `vertical-align: top;` in your badge class rule.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2hxak/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

`display: inline-block;` is messing this up. Use `float: left;` instead (possibly with `clear: left;` to make sure every badge is on a new line). ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sumurai8/evvyN/))

Comment: Using `float: left;`: No more extra space but I have to write more CSS to keep the badge align center